# how to code player to move on mobile device touch screen input using ui button

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton, touch

I was wondering how to make my player move when I click a UI button in unity 2D. I am more confused on how to code the UI button to receive the input and move the player until the UI button is not pressed but would still be happy if someone could help with the movement as well but the button is more important. I am coding in c#

I want it to work something like this but obviously this is just shoddy pseudocode:

public void whenClicked();
{
if (leftButton is clicked)
move player left

if (rightButton is clicked)
move player right

if (upButton is clicked)
move player jump
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move a character there is 2 main ways: moving by Transform component (since you have 2D game you have most likely RectTransform on character) and by Rigidbody component.

TRANSFORM:
script on your button should look so:

```
public GameObject character; // The link to the character you want to move
private bool doMove; // whether the character must move or not
public float speed;

private void OnMouseDown () {
    doMove = true;
}
private void Update () {
    if (doMove) {
        character.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

It is moving right. You can also use Vector3.up, Vector3.left, Vector3.down, Vector3.forward, Vector3.back
Experiment with the variable speed and you'll get what you want.

But here I have a question. I have just seen that in your question you write that you use UI button. Do you mean an Image with BoxCollider or literally GameObject with Button component. If it is the second, I recommend you to delete component Button from your button_objects because just a script with OnMouseDown function is enough. This script must be added to all your buttons (up, right...). Also you should add next strings to your code:

```
public Vector3 direction;

// and also edit Update function this way:
    if (doMove) {
        character.transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
```

Then in Unity set the next parameters in this script:

> For button up direction = x=0, y=1, z=0 
> For button down direction = x=0, y=-1, z=0
> For button right direction = x=1, y=1, z=0
> For button left direction = x=-1, y=1, z=0

Thus, every button will move character in its own direction;

What about rigidBody. If you use it, you can make the same thing, but replace the function [transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) by [GetComponent().AddForce(Vector3.right*speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html);
But personally I think that moveing by Transform is easier

Comment: But you can use Button component anyway. But here you'd better put all the buttons into one object (called for example "Game_Buttons"). Change OnMouseDown function on other with another name (for example Move() or MoveCharacter()) and add script with this function not to every button, but only to Game_Buttons object. Afterwards, in Button component on Buttons you should specify a link to this Game_Buttons and choose function Move_Charcter(). So if you want to use Button component, not BoxCollider2D, write. I will explant it more detailed)

Comment: I tried using the UI buttons and attaching a script with functions such as MoveRight() and it works to move my player, but how do you make it so that you can hold the button down and it continuously moves the player?

Comment: As far as I know, Button component cannot follow the long tap. It can only call some function when there was a click (mouse click or finger touch). So, if you want to do some function every frame when there is a click in your up-right-left buttons you'd better add them all BoxCollider2D and use function `OnMouseDrag()`. It calls every frame, when there is the mouse is clamped over the object, even if it doesn't actually drag. And also you must add your script with functions to every button. In function OnMouseDrag() you may check what side object must move by name of button that is clicked

Comment: By the way, could you put like on my another answer about OnMouse functions. The thing is that I need only 1 point to become able to add comments to questions (not to answers) and it is very useful thing:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Component BoxCollider2D to your object and write function

```
OnMouseDown(){} // calls one frame when there was touch of boxcollider
OnMouseDrag(){} // calls every frame when there is touch of boxcollider
OnMouseUP(){} // calls one framу when there touch of boxcollider was stopped
```

This functions works perfectly not only in PC but on Android, too.

Comment: As far as my bad English allows me to understand your question, do you also need help about the movement of the object itself? If yes, write and I explain it to you.

Comment: yes please if you don't mind i think it would be helpful

Comment: I'd rather write about it in another answer  after about an hour